# How can I remove files which contain special characters and Latin-1 characters?

Tags: filenames, special-characters, file-management

I have 2 files in a directory named `App` on my Ubuntu mahcine.
I want to remove those 2 files completely from that directory, but when I try to remove them using `rm -rf`, they are not deleted.

I can't even see these 2 files in the `App` folder in the GUI.
`ls al` in the directory returns:

```
ls: cannot access Notepad_verify���,;()p_151003101035_Results_2800.rpt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access M J_g ;w-%()�t�{,l]_120424113032_Results_2800.rpt: No such file or directory
total 24
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 20480 Oct  7 16:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root  4096 Oct  7  2015 ..
-?????????  ? ?    ?        ?            ? M J_g ;w-%()?t?{,l]_120424113032_Results_2800.rpt
-?????????  ? ?    ?        ?            ? Notepad_verify???,;()p_151003101035_Results_2800.rpt
```

If I try `rm -rf`, then command runs successfully but the files are not deleted. They are still in the 'App' directory.

I also tried to remove the complete directory.

With `rm -rf App/`, I get:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘AppData/’: Directory not empty
```

And `rm -rf App/*` seems to run successfully but the files are still in the `App` folder.

I can't even display the permission or time & date details.
I can't use `rm`, `mv`, or `cp` commands on these files.

How can I delete these files?

Comment: Does `fsck` report a clean filesystem?

Comment: `fsck` on which? I ran 'fsck' on my current directory where these 2 files lies. It shows me like this.: 
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sda8 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
Is this what you need?or something else? please let me know.

Comment: What filesystem is this directory on? How is it mounted? Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `df /path/to/App`. Can you create a file and delete it? Try `touch foo; rm foo` in the `App` directory. Also, try unmounting the filesystem where this is mounted, and running `fsck` on it (it will be the `/dev/sdX` from the output of `df`).

Comment: Output of 'df' command:

Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1        1889800 367052   1425088  21% /media/497f78bd-93d0-4f5e-8a32-8a279bade51a

YES, I can create and delete 'foo' on same(App) directory.
Output of after unmount the FS, there is a '/dev/sdc1' in my case.

Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              985636    12    985624   1% /dev

Comment: `umount /dev/sdc1`then, if umount correctly `fsck /dev/sdc1` accept all. remount, files should be deletable.

Comment: @Archemar: output of 'fsck /dev/sdc1'

~# fsck /dev/sdc1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdc1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Is this correct one or not? and all other files are remove, copy, move without any problem only these 2 files in this 'App' folder are not accessible and problem is that I don't want to format whole file system(sd card).

Answer (score 1):

App folder make me think about a Liberkey or such, probably not closed cleanly.

Now you have to fix the filesystem, this is the fsck (FileSystem Consistensy Check).

If disk is mounted you can't fsck

1. unmount disk : `umount /dev/sdc1` (see device busy below)
2. check filesystem `fsck -y /dev/sdc1`
3. remount disk (if this is an usb key, just unplug/replug).

In case of "`cannot umount /dev/sdc1 device busy`"

- `cd /tmp`
- close all other terminal/connection
- if that still failed, you may have application using file on disk, try a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `find`.

`find -name '*.rpt' -delete`

Comment: I ran above command and it ran successfully, but when I am doing 'ls -al' then again files are still there, don't know why they aren't removing..!!
Is there any way to delete it completely.
Result of 'ls -al' same as first(above in question).